# RVM says "installed rails", but rails not installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

here's my history of commands:

```
$ rvm --version

rvm 1.24.7 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, 
Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

...

```
$ gem install rails

1 gem installed
```

then

```
$ rails version 

rails not installed
```

So I tried

```
sudo apt-get install rails
```

Now I have Rails 3 installed but I want Rails 4. Can somebody help?

I also don't know how to check the version of Ruby. I tried Ruby v, Ruby version, Ruby --version, and all of them returned

```
/home/max/.rvm/bin/ruby: line 6: /home/max/.rvm/bin/ruby: Argument list too long
/home/max/.rvm/bin/ruby: line 6: /home/max/.rvm/bin/ruby: Success
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the sequence that I use.

```
$ rvm use --create 2.1.0@appname
$ gem install rails
$ rails -v
```

I think your problem was in the `rails version` command, `cause it's not actually there.

Answer (score 0):

Install `ruby` 2.0.0

```
$ rvm install ruby-2.0.0
```

then install `rails` 4 gem

```
$ gem install rails --version=4.0
```

to check versions of `ruby` installed do

```
rvm list
```